# How to instantiate an array of custom classes in Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I'm new to AS3 and I'm getting this error while trying to implement OO style code.

```
  Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 0.
```

When I try to:

```
var countries:Country = new Country(10);
```

Normally this would work in Java or C++, so I'm not sure what's up!?

Here is my custom class.

package  {

```
public class Country {

    var cName:String = "noName"; 
    public function Country() {
        // constructor code
    }

    public function setName(n:String):void {
        cName = n;
    }
    public function getName():String {
        return cName;
    }


}

}
```

Comment: Arrays in as3 are more like arrays in JavaScript and less like Java. Still, if you want a limited sized, typed array, you can use a typed [Vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html): `var countries:Vector.<Country> = new Vector.<Country>(10,true);`

Comment: Also, in as3 you have getter/setters (somewhat similar to those in C#): `public function set name(n:String):void{cName = n} public function get name():String{return cName;}//then with an instance: country.name = "A";//setter trace(country.name);//getter` although, using java style like what you now is a bit faster I think.

Comment: This '`new Country(10)`' is not array nor in C++, nor in Java !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing 10 to the constructor, which is not what you want to do.  To instantiate an array of instances, try something like this:

```
var countries:Array = []
var country:Country;
for (var i:uint = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    country = new Country()
    country.setName("Country_" + i);
    countries.push(country)
}
```

Comment: +1. Consider using Vector.<Country> instead of Array for AS3 - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html

Answer (score 0):

your constructor function `public function Country() {}` not have an argument, but you give 10, must go wrong.

ActionScript's array not like c++, don't need element type `<Country>`

you want to save class in array is simple: `var arr:Array = [new Country()]`